# Managed Memory StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, memory-management

Problem: JVM OOME caused by appending large files to a String or StringBuilder

Proposed solution: Inspired by the `org.apache.axis.attachments.ManagedMemoryDataSource` class I have wrote a class that keeps a StringBuilder buffer to a certain maximum. When that maximum is reached the class flush the contents of the StringBuilder to disk, and all subsequent appends are done to disk.

is there any custom class out there that accomplish this?

am I on the right track?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, actually I am implementing a custom solution. At this moment it doesn't implement any interface. First I want to solve the problem, then I will decide if conforming to any of those interfaces will report me any more benefits (right now I think so, but I don't know if i will have the time)

Comment: Use File.separator instead of hardcoding "/" otherwise it won't work in Unix.

Comment: good advice Lluis. Thanks. As it is now it's more academical than practical, but I will use File.separator in the production version for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final version:

```
package aytos.util.gestion;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.UUID;    

public class ManagedMemoryStringBuilder implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static String tmpPath;

  private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

  private File tmpFile;

  private static int MAX_BUFFER = 262144;// 256KB

  static
  {
    // get temporal path to store the file
    tmpPath = /* TODO initialize your temporal path here */;
    if(!"".equals(tmpPath))
    {
      tmpPath += File.separator + "ManagedMemoryStringBuilder";
      File folder = new File(tmpPath);
      if(!folder.exists())
      {
        if(!folder.mkdirs())
        {
          tmpPath = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void setTmpPath(String tmpPath1)
  {
    tmpPath = tmpPath1;
  }

  public static String getTmpPath()
  {
    return tmpPath;
  }

  public File getFile()
  {
    return tmpFile;
  }

  public ManagedMemoryStringBuilder append(String content)
  {
    if(tmpFile != null)
    {// already on disk
      writeToDisk(content);
    }
    else if(!"".equals(tmpPath) && ((buffer.length() + content.length()) > MAX_BUFFER))
    {// buffer overflow, write to disk
      flushToDisk();
      writeToDisk(content);
    }
    else
    {// great, can store in memory
      buffer.append(content);
    }
    return this;
  }

  public ManagedMemoryStringBuilder append(InputStream is)
  {
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      // attemp to fill the whole buffer
      char[] cBuf = new char[MAX_BUFFER - buffer.length()];
      int read = reader.read(cBuf);
      buffer.append(cBuf);

      if(read != -1)
      {// something is left on the reader, so we have to flush the buffer to disk and resume writing
        flushToDisk();
        ReadableByteChannel in = null;
        FileChannel out = null;
        try
        {
          in = Channels.newChannel(is);
          out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile,true).getChannel();
          ByteBuffer bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_BUFFER);

          while(in.read(bytebuf) > 0)
          { // Read data from Channel into ByteBuffer
            // flip the buffer which set the limit to current position, and position to 0.
            bytebuf.flip();
            out.write(bytebuf); // Write data from ByteBuffer to file
            bytebuf.clear(); // For the next read
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          if(in != null)
          {
            try
            {
              in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
              // nothing to do
            }
          }
          if(out != null)
          {
            try
            {
              out.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
              // nothing to do
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return this;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public ManagedMemoryStringBuilder append(ManagedMemoryStringBuilder content)
  {
    if(!"".equals(tmpPath) && content.tmpFile != null)
    {// content already on disk
      if(tmpFile == null)
      {// have to tranfer to disk
        flushToDisk();
      }
      try
      {
        FileChannel in = null;
        FileChannel out = null;
        try
        {
          in = new FileInputStream(content.tmpFile).getChannel();
          out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile,true).getChannel();
          ByteBuffer bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_BUFFER);

          while(in.read(bytebuf) > 0)
          { // Read data from file into ByteBuffer
            // flip the buffer which set the limit to current position, and position to 0.
            bytebuf.flip();
            out.write(bytebuf); // Write data from ByteBuffer to file
            bytebuf.clear(); // For the next read
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          if(in != null)
          {
            try
            {
              in.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
              // nothing to do
            }
          }
          if(out != null)
          {
            try
            {
              out.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
              // nothing to do
            }
          }
        }
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      append(content.toString());
    }
    return this;
  }

  private void flushToDisk()
  {
    tmpFile = new File(tmpPath + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID());
    writeToDisk(buffer.toString());
    buffer = null;
  }

  private void writeToDisk(String content)
  {
    try
    {
      Writer output = null;
      try
      {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFile.getCanonicalPath(),true),MAX_BUFFER);
        output.write(content);
      }
      finally
      {
        if(output != null)
        {
          try
          {
            output.close();
          }
          catch(IOException io)
          {
            // Nothing to do
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public boolean isFile()
  {
    return tmpFile != null;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    try
    {
      if(isFile())
      {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile.getCanonicalPath());
        FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer mmb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,0,fc.size());
        byte[] buffer str = new byte[(int)fc.size()];
        mmb.get(buffer);
        fis.close();
        fc.close();
        return new String(str);
      }
      else
      {
        return buffer.toString();
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a reasonable solution, but when are these files deleted?

Comment: We have a background process that take care of that periodically

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a bigger virtual memory in your OS and specify a bigger heap for the JVM? It looks like trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I have very high memory demmands from large Base64 files that can get the JVM OOME pretty often, so augmenting the heap it's only a temporal measure until a bigger file arrives and then evrything blow up.,,

Comment: Then you some Base64 Reader that allows you to deal with these huge files as streams.

Comment: Try http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html

Comment: Thanks Lluis, please see my code above. I have big Base64 files, and also small ones. I don't want all files in disk, only those that can bemocome a memory bottlenbeck (in my code above 100K for example), so I came with the idea of a class that encapsulates all that logic behaind the scenes